# Boost Log 1.54 on Mac OS and QtCreator (G++)

Tags: c++, macos, qt, boost, qt4

How can one use logging library from Boost on version 1.54 ? (I'm using QtCreator and have successfully used boost/filesystem)

I read that the logging lib is now part of Boost, but I can't make it work on MacOs:

My `.pro` file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-10-30T14:34:26
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Fottopic
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    configwindow.cpp \
    windowmanager.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    configwindow.h \
    windowmanager.h

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR += /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/lib
LIBS += -lboost_system\
        -lboost_filesystem\
        -lboost_log\
        -lboost_log_setup
```

Output when building:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend::~text_file_backend()", referenced from:
      boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend>::destroy() in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend::construct(boost::filesystem::path const&, std::_Ios_Openmode, unsigned long, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_function<bool ()()> const&, bool)", referenced from:
      void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend::construct<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::file_name, char const [11]> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::file_name, char const [11]> const&)in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend::flush()", referenced from:
      void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::basic_sink_frontend::flush_backend_impl<boost::mutex, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend>(boost::mutex&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend&, mpl_::bool_<true>)in main.o
  "boost::detail::get_tss_data(void const*)", referenced from:
      boost::thread_specific_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::formatting_context>::get() constin main.o
  "boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)", referenced from:
      boost::thread_specific_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::formatting_context>::reset(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::formatting_context*)in main.o
      boost::thread_specific_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::formatting_context>::~thread_specific_ptr()in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend::consume(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::feed_record<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::fake_mutex, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend>(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::fake_mutex&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend&)in main.o
      void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::feed_record<boost::mutex, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend>(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::mutex&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend&)in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::default_attribute_names::message()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::expressions::tag::message::get_name()  in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::code_convert(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::locale const&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >& boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::formatted_write<wchar_t>(wchar_t const*, long)in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::once_block_sentry::enter_once_block() const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::once_block_sentry::executed() constin main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::once_block_sentry::rollback()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::once_block_sentry::~once_block_sentry()in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::once_block_sentry::commit()", referenced from:
      boost::array<std::pair<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::type_info_wrapper, void*>, 2ul> const& boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::type_sequence_dispatcher<boost::mpl::vector2<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > > >::get_dispatching_map<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::binder1st<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::output_fun, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&> >()in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::find(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name) const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::visitation_result boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_visitor_invoker<boost::mpl::vector2<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > >, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none>::operator()<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::binder1st<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::output_fun, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&> >(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::binder1st<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::output_fun, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>) constin main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::end() const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::visitation_result boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_visitor_invoker<boost::mpl::vector2<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > >, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none>::operator()<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::binder1st<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::output_fun, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&> >(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::binder1st<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::output_fun, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>) constin main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::attach_attribute_name_info(boost::exception&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::visitation_result boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_visitor_invoker<boost::mpl::vector2<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > >, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none>::operator()<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::binder1st<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::output_fun, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&> >(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::binder1st<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::output_fun, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>) constin main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend::set_file_collector(boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::file::collector> const&)", referenced from:
      boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend> > boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::add_file_log<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::file_name, char const [11]> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::file_name, char const [11]> const&)in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend::scan_for_files(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::file::scan_method, bool)", referenced from:
      boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend> > boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::add_file_log<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::file_name, char const [11]> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::file_name, char const [11]> const&)in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::get()", referenced from:
      boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend> > boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::add_file_log<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::file_name, char const [11]> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::file_name, char const [11]> const&)in main.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::add_sink(boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::sink> const&)", referenced from:
      boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend> > boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::add_file_log<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::file_name, char const [11]> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::file_name, char const [11]> const&)in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Fottopic.app/Contents/MacOS/Fottopic] Error 1
17:48:19: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Fottopic (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
```

Comment: Have you built Boost.Log? Does it appear on the linker search path? Note that it consists of 2 libs: `libboost_log` and `libboost_log_setup`.

Comment: I installed Boost trough `brew install boost` and the libs are appendend to the path. Do I need to install something else?

Comment: "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" - what version boost you have installed? try adding -m32 flag when compiling your program. It looks like you are trying to link x86 libs to x86_64 program.

Comment: @Maquefel the curious thing about it is that libbost_filesystem is working, but libbost_log isn't. So I don't think is something related to the architecture.